# C++ templated classes gives `error: non-template X used as template`

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The question is why doesn't this code compile and specifically why do I get some weird compilation errors like

`error: non-template ‘C_Iterator’ used as template` ?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>  // fot std::enable_if
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct Container{

  template <bool Is_Const>
  struct C_Iterator{

    using value_type        = T;
    using pointer           = T*;
    using reference         = T&;
    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

    T* p;

    // args c-tors
    C_Iterator(T *p_): p(p_) {}
    // Copy
    C_Iterator(const C_Iterator<Is_Const>& other) = default;

    template<bool Was_Const, class = typename std::enable_if<Is_Const || !Was_Const>::type>
    C_Iterator(const C_Iterator<Was_Const>& other) : p{other.p}{}

    C_Iterator &operator=(const C_Iterator &other){
        p = other.p;
        return *this;
    }

    reference operator*() {return *p;}

    // some other stuff here
  };

  using iterator = C_Iterator<false>;
  using const_iterator = C_Iterator<true>;

  Container(T v) { storage = new int[1]; storage[0]=v; }
  ~Container() { delete storage;  }

  inline iterator       begin()       { return iterator(storage);}
  inline const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(storage);}

  T* storage;

};


template <class T>
struct Iterable_Wrapper{

  template <bool Is_Const>
  struct W_Iterator{

    using value_type        = T;
    using pointer           = T*;
    using reference         = T&;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    using c_iterator = typename Container<T>::C_Iterator<Is_Const>;

    c_iterator it;

    // args c-tors
    W_Iterator( c_iterator it_ ): it(it_) {}

    // Copy
    W_Iterator(const W_Iterator<Is_Const>& other) = default;

    template<bool Was_Const, class = typename std::enable_if<Is_Const || !Was_Const>::type>
    W_Iterator(const W_Iterator<Was_Const>& other) : it{other.it}{}

    W_Iterator &operator=(const W_Iterator &other){
        it = other.it;
        return *this;
    }

    reference operator*() {return *it;}

    // some other stuff here
  };

  using iterator = W_Iterator<false>;
  using const_iterator = W_Iterator<true>;

  Iterable_Wrapper(T v) : wrapped_container(v) {}
  ~Iterable_Wrapper() {}

  inline iterator       begin()       { return iterator(wrapped_container.begin());}
  inline const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(wrapped_container.begin());}

  Container<T> wrapped_container;

};

int main()
{
  Container<int> c{5};
  auto it { c.begin() };
  std::cout << *it << std::endl;

  const Container<int> c2{10};
  auto it2 { c2.begin() };
  std::cout << *it2 << std::endl;


  Iterable_Wrapper<int> w{15};
  auto it3 { w.begin() };
  std::cout << *it3 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

To give a bit more context, I'm trying to get a re-implementation of a few data structures as an exercise and I'm now struggling at a "composite" data structure ( a HashSet, an over-simplified version of an `unordered_set` ) implemented as a `vector` of buckets with a `linked_list` in each of them.
Both vector and list implementation are my own, so it's likely the fault in the implementation is uphill and that's why the minimal example is so long.. I needed to include both "mock" classes.

As I said, the above code cannot compile and if I run g++ file.cpp -std=c++11 gives me

`file.cpp:61:57: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token`

i.e. he's expecting `using c_iterator = typename Container<T>::C_Iterator<Is_Const>;` to be `using c_iterator = typename Container<T>::C_Iterator` instead.

Weird, and indeed if I run it complains that 
`error: ‘typename Container<int>::C_Iterator’ names ‘template<bool Is_Const> struct Container<int>::C_Iterator’, which is not a type`

so the template should be there! What's wrong with my code?

**EDIT**: I got the brillant idea to try to compile with `clang++` and it suggests that I modify line 61 into

`using c_iterator = typename Container<T>::template C_Iterator<Is_Const>;`

and now it works; I have however no idea what the extra `::template` is doing, so the question stands .. why did I have to do it that way? what is `::template` hinting to the compiler that allows the code to compile now?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
using c_iterator = typename Container<T>::template C_Iterator<Is_Const>;
```

Comment: thanks, that's it indeed as clang kindly suggested. I'll have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) to see why it is the case